# What is the difference between the tensor flow and the optical flow?

Tags: image-processing, matlab-figure, tensorflow, pixel, opticalflow

Can any one give me a accurate response to this question:

**What is the difference between the  tensor flow and the optical  flow?**

THANKS

Comment: it sounds like a beginning of a bad joke :)

Comment: Did you even try to use Google to look for both terms before asking this question? Your Google-Fu skills need a lot of work.

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow is the code released by Google for implementing Deep Learning - in the field of Machine Intelligence/Neural Networks.
https://www.tensorflow.org/

Optical flow is way of analysing successive frames of a video such that features are tracked as they move from pixel to pixel - in the field of Computer Vision
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow